# I want to save the selected radio button into the database? How can I accomplish that in django?

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-views, radio-button

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
# Create your models here.
# from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
from enum import Enum
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

class Username(AbstractUser):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, default=None, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    REQUIRED_FEILDS = []
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Option(models.TextChoices):
        OPTION1 = 'OPTION1', _('OPTION1')
        OPTION2 = 'OPTION2', _('OPTION2')
        OPTION3 = 'OPTION3', _('OPTION3')
        OPTION4 = 'OPTION4', _('OPTION4')



class Question(models.Model):
    # id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question=models.CharField(max_length=600)
    option1=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    option2=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    option3=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    option4=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)    
    difficulty=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    exam=models.BooleanField()
    key=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    correct_answer = models.CharField(max_length=7,choices=Option.choices,default=None,)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Answer(models.Model):
    username=models.ForeignKey(Username,max_length=200, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(
        max_length=7,
        choices=Option.choices,
        default=None,
    )
    surety=models.PositiveIntegerField( null=True)
    difficulty=models.PositiveIntegerField( null=True)
   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth  import authenticate,  login, logout
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from ada.models import Question
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
from django import forms

# class TestScreen(ListView):
#     paginate_by = 6
#     model = Question

# from .forms import CommentForm

# def post_comment(request, username_id):
#    if request.method == 'POST':
#        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
#        if form.is_valid():
#            data = form.cleaned_data
#            blog = get_object_or_404(Practise, id=username_id)
#            Comment.objects.create(
#               question_id = question_id)

def viewtemplate(request, username):

    student = Answer.objects.get(id = username)

    form = templateform(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.username = student
            form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = templateform()
    return render(request, 'practise.html', {'form': form})

def index(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request,'index.html')

   
# @login_required(login_url = '/login')
# def quiz(request, myid):
#     quiz = Quiz.objects.get(id=myid)
#     return render(request, "quiz.html", {'quiz':quiz})

def Signup(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    if request.method=="POST":   
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        first_name=request.POST['first_name']
        last_name=request.POST['last_name']
        password = request.POST['password1']
        confirm_password = request.POST['password2']
        
        if password != confirm_password:
            return redirect('/register')
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.save()
        return render(request, 'login.html')  
    return render(request, "signup.html")

# def testscreen(request):
#     return render(request, 'questions.html')

# def quizData (request):
#     context = {'quiz' : quizData }
#     return render (request, testscreen, context)

def Login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    if request.method=="POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html") 
    return render(request, "login.html")
def Practise(request):
    questions_list = Question.objects.get_queryset().order_by('id')
    paginator = Paginator(questions_list, 1) 
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    # if request.user.is_authenticated:

    #     return render(request, 'practise.html',)
    if request.method=="POST":
                answer = request.POST.get('html')
                print(request.POST)
                # difficulty = request.POST['difficulty']
                # surety=request.POST['surety']
                # answer.save()
              
            
                return render(request, 'practise.html' ,{'page_obj': page_obj})
       
      

def Profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'users-profile.html')

def FAQ(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'pages-faq.html')

def Contact(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'pages-contact.html')

def Logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect(request,'login.html')

def question(request):
    # questions_list = Question.objects.all().order_by(Lower("key"))
    questions_list = Question.objects.get_queryset().values("key").annotate(n=models.Count("pk"))
    practise_questions =  Question.objects.filter(key= 'questions_list').all()
    print(practise_questions)
    # a = Question.objects.filter(key='C.1.1')
    # print(a.count())

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'questions.html', {'questions_list': questions_list})


def practise(request):
        print(request)
        questions_list = Question.objects.get_queryset().order_by('id')
        # answers_list = Answer.objects.all()
        # print(answers_list)
        paginator = Paginator(questions_list, 1) 
        page_number = request.POST.get('page_no')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        print(request.GET)
        # if request.user.is_authenticated:
        #     return render(request, "try.html",{'page_obj': page_obj})
        if request.method=="POST":
                answer = request.POST.get('answer')
                difficulty = request.POST.get('myRange')
                surety=request.POST.get('surety')
                # Answer = ()
                # answer_submit = Answer(answer='answer')
                # answer_submit.save()
                # answer_submit.answer = answer
                # answer_submit.difficulty = difficulty
                # answer_submit.surety = surety
                # answer_submit.save()
                # print(request.POST)

                # User_ans = get_user_model()
                # user = User_ans.objects.create_user(answer, difficulty, surety)
                #user.answer = answer
                # user.difficulty = difficulty
                #user.save()
            
        return render(request, "try.html", {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

try.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Practise Test {% endblock %}
{% block css %}
<style>
      .head1 {
    color: bisque;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans';
  }

  .head2 {
    color: cyan;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans';
  }
  
  </style>

  {% endblock %}

  {% block body %}
  <div class="btn-wrapper"> 

  <div class="row py-5 p-4 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">
    
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="bg-light rounded-pill px-4 py-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold"
            style="color:black;font-weight:bold">Practise Test</div>
        <br>
        {% for question in page_obj %}
        <form class="row g-4" method="POST" action="/try/">{% csrf_token %}
          
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <li class="list-group-item active font-weight-bold">{{ question.id }}. {{ question.question }}</legend></li>
              <label for="{{ question.option1 }}" class="form-label" style="font-weight: bold;"><i>
                {{ question.option1 }}</i></label>
                <input type="radio" style="text-align: center;"value="{{ question.option1 }}"
                    class="form-control" id="html1" name="option">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label for="{{ question.option2 }}" class="form-label" style="font-weight: bold;"><i>
                {{ question.option2 }}</i></label>
                <input type="radio" style="text-align: center;" value="{{ question.option2 }}"
                    class="form-control" id="html2" name="option">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label for="{{ question.option3 }}" class="form-label" style="font-weight: bold;"><i>
                {{ question.option3 }}</i></label>
                <input type="radio" style="text-align: center;"value="{{ question.option3 }}"
                    class="form-control" id="html3" name="option">
            </div>
            <label for="{{ question.option4 }}" class="form-label" style="font-weight: bold;"><i>
              {{ question.option4 }}</i></label>
              <input type="radio" style="text-align: center;"value="{{ question.option4 }}"
                  class="form-control" id="html4" name="option">
            </div>

           
            {% endfor %}
           <div class="slid">
<h3>
<b> <i> Difficulty </i> </b>
</h3>
<p>Slide according to difficulty of question:</p>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input
    type="range"
    min="1"
    max="5"
    value="value"
    class="slider"
    id="myRange"
    name="difficulty_slider"
  />
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function () {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
};

</script>
<h3>Surety: </h3>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input
    type="range"
    min="1"
    max="5"
    value="value"
    class="slider"
    id="justRange"
    name="surety_slider"
  />
  <p>Value: <span id="realDemo"></span></p>
  <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function () {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
    };

    var slider = document.getElementById("justRange");
    var display = document.getElementById("realDemo");
    display.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function () {
      display.innerHTML = this.value;
    };


  </script>
    

                  {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                 
                  <button method="post" type="submit" class="action-btn checkRequired Submit" name="action" value="Submit"> previous</button>
                  <input type="hidden" name="page_no" value="{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">
                  {% endif %}


                  Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
 

                  {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                  <button method="post" type="submit" class="action-btn checkRequired Submit" name="action" value="Submit"> next</button>
                  <input type="hidden" name="page_no" value="{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">    
                  {% endif %}
         

            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> -->
            </form>
            <br>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  {% endblock %}
```

I have attached the necessary views, models and html files for references. Also,
In html page there are radio buttons inside of form, where clicking Submit button has to save all selected radio buttons into the database. Is there any way to do that? Any solution would be of lot more help.

Answer (score 0):

in views.py you can use:

```
# If not using required attribute in HTML
seleted_option = request.POST.get('option')

# If using required it is suggested to use
seleted_option = request.POST['option']
```